# ASP.Net Core Authentication not working after upgrade from 2.2 to 3

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.0

I have a web application (type MVC) in ASP.NET Core 2.2 with authentication enabled (this was generated with dotnet aspnet-codegenerator identity). All great until there. I had to upgrade the project to ASP.Net Core 3.0 and the authentication stopped working. 
¿Can anybody help me ?

I think I have made the described points in the [documentation from Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio), but I don't know what is the problem.

References of the project:

```
<ItemGroup>        
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="3.0.0" />        
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="3.0.0" />        
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI" Version="3.0.0" />        
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="3.0.0" />        
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="3.0.0">
  <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
  <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
</PackageReference>        
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Identity.Core" Version="3.0.0" />        
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="3.0.0" />        
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Utils" Version="3.0.0" />        
<PackageReference Include="RestSharp" Version="106.6.10" />
<PackageReference Include="Serilog" Version="2.9.0" />
<PackageReference Include="System.Linq.Queryable" Version="4.3.0" />
```

When I test the project in debug in VS the option Login leads to: 
localhost/?area=Identity&page=%2FAccount%2FLogin

Before of the migration, it led to: 
localhost/Identity/Account/Login

If I load it manually, it gives error 404

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllersWithViews();

        services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
        });

        services.AddDbContext<WalletContext>(item => item.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("WalletConn")));
        services.AddCloudscribePagination();
        services.AddAuthentication();
    }

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseCookiePolicy();

        app.UseRouting();                  

        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
               name: "pagingMovements",
               pattern: "pager/{p:int?}",
               defaults: new { controller = "Movements", action = "Details" }
               );
        });
    }
```

Class IdentityHostingStartup
[assembly: HostingStartup(typeof(GLB.Wallet.Backoffice.Areas.Identity.IdentityHostingStartup))]

```
public class IdentityHostingStartup : IHostingStartup
{
    public void Configure(IWebHostBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.ConfigureServices((context, services) => {
            services.AddDbContext<IdentityDataContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(
                    context.Configuration.GetConnectionString("BackofficeConn")));

            services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<IdentityDataContext>();
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: @KirkLarkin Hi, Yes I do. Before I executed this commands 
dotnet tool install --global dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator
dotnet aspnet-codegenerator identity 

I have the folder Areas, Identity, Data, Pages, and the class IdentityHostingStartup.cs

What am I missing? :( Thanks

Comment: It looks it's just one thing missing, which is covered in the linked dupe. Let me know if that doesn't resolve it and I'll reopen this.

Comment: @KirkLarkin Oh man !!! I really appreciate your help. It works perfectly. Thanks again. Have a good day :)

Comment: You're welcome. I've raised an issue against the docs to see if this can be added to the migration guide.